# Addidng a `transitionend` event listener to an element only causes the animation to fire in reverse

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I can't seem to make the opening part of this transition work, only the closing part.

The reason I've structured my html the way that I have, is because I need to use `display: none` and `display:block` to actually remove the element from the document flow. Using `display` to show and hide elements is problematic generally speaking when combining with animation, so the idea is to have a container element be subject to the `display` rules, and have the child element animate.

See my code and/or [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/tezigoqebe/edit?html,css,js,output):

```
<button id="gallery_menu__trigger">Click me now</button>

<div id="gallery_menu__list">
  <div id="gallery_menu__list_items" class="gallery_menu__revealable">Hello!</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#gallery_menu__list {
  display:none;
}

.gallery_menu__revealable {
  transform: translatey(-20px);
  opacity: 0;
  will-change: transform, opacity;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.gallery_menu__revealable--visible {
  transform: translateX(0);
  opacity: 1;
}

.gallery_menu__revealable--animating {
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
```

And JS:

```
function init () {
  var galleryMenuTrigger = document.getElementById('gallery_menu__trigger');
  var galleryMenuList = document.getElementById('gallery_menu__list');
  var galleryMenuListItems = document.getElementById('gallery_menu__list_items');

  galleryMenuTrigger.addEventListener('click', toggleGalleryMenu(galleryMenuList, galleryMenuListItems), false)
  galleryMenuListItems.addEventListener('transitionend', onTransitionEnd(galleryMenuListItems), false)
}


function toggleGalleryMenu (galleryMenuList, galleryMenuListItems) {
  return function () {
    if (galleryMenuList.style.display === 'block') {
      addAnimatingClass(galleryMenuListItems)
      closeGalleryMenuListItems(galleryMenuListItems);
      setTimeout(closeGalleryMenu(galleryMenuList), 300);
      return;
    }

    displayGalleryMenu(galleryMenuList)
    addAnimatingClass(galleryMenuListItems)
    displayGalleryMenuListItems(galleryMenuListItems);
  }
}

function addAnimatingClass (galleryMenuListItems) {
  galleryMenuListItems.classList.add('gallery_menu__revealable--animating')
}

function onTransitionEnd (galleryMenuListItems) {
  return function () {
     return galleryMenuListItems.classList.remove('gallery_menu__revealable--animating');
  }
}

function displayGalleryMenu (galleryMenuList) {
  galleryMenuList.style.display = 'block'
}

function closeGalleryMenu (galleryMenuList) {
  return function() {
    return galleryMenuList.style.display = 'none'
  }
}

function displayGalleryMenuListItems (galleryMenuListItems) {  
  return galleryMenuListItems.classList.add('gallery_menu__revealable--visible')
}

function closeGalleryMenuListItems (galleryMenuListItems) {
  return galleryMenuListItems.classList.remove('gallery_menu__revealable--visible')
}



init();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close to solution, I've made a little changes, I've removed `addAnimatingClass(galleryMenuListItems)` and changed `displayGalleryMenuListItems(galleryMenuListItems`. Look:

```
function displayGalleryMenuListItems (galleryMenuListItems) {  
  return setTimeout(function(){
   galleryMenuListItems.classList.add('gallery_menu__revealable--visible')
  },300)
}
```

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xg5fhyst/

Comment: This fixed it. Seems like an odd thing to have to do, but it worked.